# Box API - Folder has children

Tags: box-api

When querying for folder contents (/folder/0/items), is there a way to tell if a sub folder entry has items (other than explicitly querying each sub folder contents?)

We'd like to show a list of items in a Folder with '+' icons next to non empty folders.
The 'size' property is no good, as it will show 0 for non empty folders having just sub folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that we've been looking into.  Your feedback on the Box Platform Trello board, and specifically on this item: https://trello.com/c/Zd0K5oPq/34-fields-to-support-sub-fields   would help Box keep a catalog of which specific problems need solving.

The rough plan is to build sub-fields support into the ?fields capability on the request.  Still being worked on, but going to be a huge powerup when released.